# Problems with building a quiz game on Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm busy with a little project on Windows Phone 7.1. I'm trying to build a quiz based game. I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2010.

I want the questions and answers to appear in random order. There appears an image with each question and after five questions the game is finished. If you have made one mistake you are a loser.

This is what I got so far:

```
namespace PhoneApp3
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private List<Quiz> _Questions = null;
        private const int _QuestionCount = 7;
        private Quiz _CurrentQuestion = null;
        private int _CurrentQuestionIndex = 0;
        private int _Missed = 0;
        private DateTime _StartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _Questions = new List<Quiz>();

            _Questions.Add(new Quiz("What is the height of the Eiffel Tower?", "324 meters", "/PhoneApp3/Images/Eiffel_Tower.png", new[] { "176 meters", "257 meters" }));
            _Questions.Add(new Quiz("Where can you find the Big Ben?", "In London", "/PhoneApp3/Images/Big_Ben.png", new[] { "In Berlin", "In Copenhagen" }));
            _Questions.Add(new Quiz("Where can you find the Tower of Pisa?", "In Italy", "/PhoneApp3/Images/Tower_of_Pisa.png", new[] { "In Spain", "In Greece" }));
            _Questions.Add(new Quiz("What is the largest city of Europe?", "Istanbul", "/PhoneApp3/Images/City.png", new[] { "Moscow", "London" }));
            _Questions.Add(new Quiz("Which country is the host of the next UEFA European Championship (2016)?", "France", "/PhoneApp3/Images/UEFA.png", new[] { "Spain", "Germany" }));
            _Questions.Add(new Quiz("Who painted The Night Watch?", "Rembrandt van Rijn", "/PhoneApp3/Images/Night_Watch.png", new[] { "Vincent van Gogh", "Pablo Picasso" }));
            _Questions.Add(new Quiz("Which is the smallest country of Europe?", "Iceland", "/PhoneApp3/Images/Eiffel_Tower.png", new[] { "Greece", "The Netherlands" }));

            StartGame();
        }

        private void StartGame()
        {
            _CurrentQuestion = null;
            _CurrentQuestionIndex = 0;
            _Missed = 0;
            _StartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

            _Questions = Shuffle(_Questions);
        }

        private List<T> Shuffle<T>(List<T> inputList)
        {
            List<T> randomList = new List<T>(inputList.Count);

            var random = new Random();
            int randomIndex = 0;
            while (inputList.Count > 0)
            {
                randomIndex = random.Next(0, inputList.Count);
                randomList.Add(inputList[randomIndex]);
                inputList.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
            }

            return randomList;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            if (e.NavigationMode == System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode.Back)
            {
                StartGame();
            }
        }

        private void btnOption1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckResult((sender as Button).Content);
        }

        private void btnOption2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckResult((sender as Button).Content);
        }

        private void btnOption3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckResult((sender as Button).Content);
        }

        private void CheckResult(object obj)
        {
            var choice = obj as string;

            if (!choice.Equals(_CurrentQuestion.Answer))
            {
                ++_Missed;
            }

            MoveToNext();
        }

        private void MoveToNext()
        {
            if (_CurrentQuestionIndex < 5)
            {
                // continue with next question
                _CurrentQuestion = _Questions[_CurrentQuestionIndex++];
                img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_CurrentQuestion.ImagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                var opties = Shuffle(new List<string>() { _CurrentQuestion.Options[0], _CurrentQuestion.Options[1], _CurrentQuestion.Answer });

                btnOption1.Content = opties[0];
                btnOption2.Content = opties[1];
                btnOption3.Content = opties[2];
            }
            else
            {
                // end of the game
                var time = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(_StartTime);

                if (_Missed > 0)
                {
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Result.xaml?win=false&time=" + time, UriKind.Relative));
                }
                else
                {
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Result.xaml?win=true&time=" + time, UriKind.Relative));
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public class Quiz
    {
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string[] Options { get; set; }

        public Quiz(string question, string answer, string imagePath, string[] options)
        {
            Question = question;
            Answer = answer;
            ImagePath = imagePath;
            Options = options;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work how I thought it would do. Questions and options don't appear, the whole game doesn't work. I can't figure out what I have to do, so I'm pretty stuck.

**EDIT**
The XAML

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="PhoneApp3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF008FFF">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Margin="12,17,12,28" Height="0"></StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto" Margin="0,36,12,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="227*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="229*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Background="#FF3EA6FF" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,656,12,0" Name="btnOption3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Click="btnOption3_Click" />
            <Button Background="#FF3EA6FF" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,500,12,0" Name="brnOption1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Click="btnOption1_Click" />
            <Button Background="#FF3EA6FF" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,578,12,0" Name="btnOption2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Click="btnOption2_Click" />
            <Image Height="276" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="96,218,96,0" Name="img" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="276" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

The problem: I don't get any data to my screen, there appears no text in the buttons e.g.

Comment: which part dint work?

Comment: You should be more precise with your issue.

Comment: You might want to show some XAML. Since "nothing is working" I would also recommend starting a new project, get something simple working, and slowly put your current code in, one buildable/workable piece at a time until you discover the mistake.

Comment: If you aren't sure what exactly is happening or what exactly isn't working it would probably help to set breakpoints throughout your application. Run your application in Debug mode. Whilst it is debugging, it might also help to set watch variables so that you can monitor the contents of your variables throughout the life of the program. Pinpoint where exactly the program is failing and tell us what errors are being thrown, if any.